Make type checker accept multiple types for a field as valid but have pydantic always coerce to one type
I'm building a wrapper for another program I'm using that takes integer-valued flags as input for setting various options. To make the interface a bit more intuitive, I'd like to have a way to automatically validate either a keyword string or the integer flag value and associate it with any other data that might be necessary for running the program with that option.
I've implemented a custom Enum class that has both a string value value and an integer flag value, and an optional data container that can hold any required data for the particular option. I've also implemented a BeforeValidator to help pydantic automatically coerce str and int types to the custom class. Here's a trimmed-down version of the code I have:
from typing import Any, Annotated, TypeVar, List, Type
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.functional_validators import BeforeValidator

class CustomEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    """Matches an Enum member based on string value or integer value"""

    def __getitem__(self, name: Any) -> Any:
        # Get the list of all the available values and flags so we can run our comparison
        values: List[Any] = list(a.value for a in self.__members__.values())
        flags: List[int] = list(a.flag for a in self.__members__.values())
        
        try:
            name = int(name)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass
        if name in values:
            name = names[values.index(name)]
        elif name in flags:
            name = names[flags.index(name)]
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise ValueError(f"{name!s} is not an enumerated value of {type(self)!s}")
        return super().__getitem__(name)

class FlagDataEnum(Enum, metaclass=CustomEnumMeta):
    """Adds data storage and an integer flag as well as a string name to Enum class"""

    def __init__(self, desc: Any, flag: int, *args: Any) -> None:
        self._value_ = desc
        self.flag = flag
        if len(args) == 1:
            args = args[0]
        self.data = args

# Generic "Enum" subclass type
E = TypeVar("E", bound=Enum)

def _coerce_value_to_data_enum(value: Any, enum_type: Type[E]) -> E:
    """Tries to convert a value to an instance of the given enum_type"""
    if isinstance(value, enum_type):
        return value
    else:
        return enum_type[value]


class Solvers(FlagDataEnum):
    runge_kutta34 = "Runge-Kutta 3/4", 1, {'predictor':3,'corrector':4}
    runge_kutta78 = "Runge-Kutta 7/8", 2, {'predictor':7,'corrector':8}
    adams_bashforth = "Adams-Bashforth", 3
    central_difference = "Central Difference", 4

CoercedEnum = Annotated[
    Solvers, 
    BeforeValidator(partial(_coerce_value_to_data_enum,enum_type = Solvers))
]

class CalculationOptions(BaseModel):
    solver: CoercedEnum = Field(default=Solvers.runge_kutta)
    init_conditions: List[int] = Field(default_factory=list)
    

This works almost exactly as I want it to. When I initialize an instance of CalculationOptions, I can pass an int or a str to CalculationOptions.solver and pydantic will happily coerce it to an instance of Solvers and raise a ValidationError if the string or integer doesn't match the values of any of the Solvers members.
But my type checker is not happy with this situation. It complains if I try to assign an integer or string to CalculationOptions.solver:
my_options = CalculationOptions(solver = 2) # "int is not compatible with Solver"

I can get the error to go away if I change the type annotation to include str and int as a union with Solver:
CoercedEnum = Annotated[
    Solvers | str | int, 
    BeforeValidator(partial(_coerce_value_to_data_enum,enum_type = Solvers))
]

But this introduces further type checking errors when I try to use the CalculationOptions.solver value, because technically it could also be a str or an int, which don't have the attributes "flag" or "value":
assert my_options.solver.flag == 2 # "int and str do not have attribute 'flag'"

Is there a way to tell python that it's OK to assign a str or an int to a model field of type CoercedEnum, but that it should never expect the value of that field to be a str or int? Am I just using pydantic in a way it wasn't designed to be used?

Related, if not duplicates: Static type checking with Pydantic data conversion, Pydantic field with custom data type and mypy.

Thanks! Indeed, duplicates. The second one at least.
